# split string in python to get one value?

Tags: python, string, list

Need help, let's assume that I have a string 'Sam-Person' in a variable called 'input'

```
name, kind = input.split('-')
```

By doing the above, I get two variable with different strings 'Sam' and 'Person'

is there a way to only get the first value name = 'Sam' without the need of the extra variable 'kind' and without having to work with lists?

When doing this, assuming that I was going to get only 'Sam':

```
name = input.split('-')
```

I get a list, and then I can access the values by index name[0] or name[1], but it is not what I want, I just want to directly get 'Sam' into the variable 'name', is there a way to do that or an alternative to split?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assign the first item directly to the variable.

```
>>> string = 'Sam-Person'
>>> name = string.split('-')[0]
>>> name
'Sam'
```

You can specify `maxsplit` argument, because you want to get only the first item.

```
>>> name = string.split('-', 1)[0]
```

Comment: One more question, where did you manage to learn that? any specif book?

Comment: @espktro, [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial) is a good starting point.

Comment: we are adressing a sinlge index postition ('0' here). You can adress more then one by i.e. `name = string.split('-')` & `print(name[0],name[1])`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the second part of the `split`, you could instead try searching the string for the index of the first `-` character and then slicing to that index:

```
string[:string.index('-')]
```

This is a little bit faster than splitting and discarding the second part because it doesn't need to create a second string instance that you don't need.

Be aware that this code will raise an exception if there's no `-` in the string, as did your original code. A solution using `split` like falsetru's will return the full string instead (which may or may not be better).

Comment: Nice alternative, I also think is better and it is what I really was looking for.I don't need the second part of the string at all.

Comment: This should be the right answer, as it is not necessary to scan the entire string (think about a huge string). Thank you for the proposal